# Prove or disprove: $\sqrt[3] {|a+b|^3+|c+d|^3} \le \sqrt[3] {|a^3+c^3|}+\sqrt[3] {|b^3+d^3|}$

Tags: real-analysis

In the process of proving a theorem, i faced this situation:

If $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$, Can we conclude that?
$\sqrt[3] {|a+b|^3+|c+d|^3} \le \sqrt[3] {|a^3+c^3|}+\sqrt[3] {|b^3+d^3|}$

I tried to raise both sides to the power of $3$. But the inequality becomes more complex than before. Maybe its not true at all!

Any hints? counterexample(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $a = 1,c=-1,d=b=0$

Then $\sqrt[3] {|a+b|^3+|c+d|^3}= 2^{1/3}$ and $\sqrt[3] {|a^3+c^3|}+\sqrt[3] {|b^3+d^3|}= 0 \not\geq 2^{1/3}$ so the inequality fails